# Peskin and Schroeder Page no. 95 Feynman Diagrams

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, propagator, regularization, wick-rotation

From Peskin and Schroeder Page no. 95,

> ... First, what happened to the large time $T$ that was taken to $\infty(1- i\epsilon)$? We glossed overit completely in this section, starting with Eq. (4.43). The place to put it back is Eq. (4.47), where instead of just integrating over $d^4z$, we should have
> \begin{align}      \lim_{T\to \infty(1- i\epsilon)}\int^T_{-T} dz^0 \int d^3z e^{-i(p_1+p_2+p_3-p_4).z}  \end{align}
> The exponential blows up as $z^0\to \infty$ or $z^0\to -\infty$ unless its arguement is purely imaginary. To achieve this, we can take $p^0 \propto (1+i\epsilon).$

How did the textbook come to this? Why does the exponential blow up at those limits? Why does argument being purely imaginary help in this not happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

P&S first replaced
$$
\int d^4z e^{iz \cdot \sum_i \ell_i} \longrightarrow \lim_{T\rightarrow \infty (1-i \epsilon)} \int_{-T}^{+T}\int d^3z e^{iz \cdot \sum_i \ell_i}
$$
The time-like part in the exponential factor is simply
$$\exp (i z^0 \ell^0) \longrightarrow \exp \lbrack i (1-i\epsilon) \tau \ell_0\rbrack  = \exp (i \tau \ell^0) \exp (\epsilon \tau \ell^0)$$ and this very last factor blows up if  $\tau \rightarrow +\infty$. This can be resolved by changing $\ell^0$ to have a small imaginary part $\ell^0 \longrightarrow \ell^0 (1+i \epsilon)$. The divergent integrand then becomes
$$
e^{i z^0 \ell^0} \longrightarrow e^{i \tau (1-i\epsilon) \ell^0 (1+i \epsilon)} = e^{i\tau \ell^0 (1+ \epsilon^2)} 
$$
and the divergence has disappeared and we can take the limit $T\rightarrow \infty$.  This prescription for giving $\ell^0$ an infinitesimal imaginary part is exactly the same as what we use for the Feynman propagator,